# Swift: Get the Number of Keys In a Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift

For swift arrays, we can simply use the `count` property to find out how many elements are in the collection. However, we can't do the same for dictionary keys. Is the only way to do this to use a for loop and counter?

```
var myDict:  [String: AnyObject] = // ... intialize dictionary with keys and values

myDict.keys.count // doesn't work
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

There is a count property on dictionary, so `myDict.count` will work.

Answer (score 13):

Why not simply use the `count` property on `myDict`?

```
myDict.count
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

**Swift 4**

Dictionary has a inbuilt `count` property.

For the number of elements in `myDict` Dictionary, you can call

```
myDict.count
```

For further reference you can check the documentation at Apple Documents in the below links,

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary
and
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3017863-count