# Firestore Swift: Get number of nested maps stored in a document

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document with fields structured something like this:
[image]

Is there any way to count the number of nested maps? So in this case, I want to show that I have two "elements",
`JGBQBnFX23Mh5NL4W8f3N1E5Czu1` and `JGBQBnFX23Mh5NL4W8f3N1E5Czu1`

Right now, I only know how to retrieve everything under "attendees" using

```
db.collection("Collection")
            .document(eventID)
            .getDocument { doc, err in
                if let err = err {
                    print(err.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                let data = doc?.data()
                let attendees = data?["attendees"]
                print(attendees)
            }
```

But I do not know how to get the total count (of my document IDs)

Keep in mind I will not be able to use arrays in my scenario. Thanks!

Comment: Once you get the `attendees` field from the document snapshot it really is just a [Swift dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary), so it becomes a matter of [getting the number of keys from a Swift dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633732/swift-get-the-number-of-keys-in-a-dictionary).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen you should have posted that as an answer instead. I think that's the solution.

Comment: I'm totally fine with you posting that yourself Kelvin! Just glad to see you got it working. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it could be fixed by changing

`let attendees = data?["attendees"]`

to

`let attendees = data?["attendees"] as? Dictionary<String, Any>`

and then you could get the total count by doing `attendees?.count`